# Waiting for a pthread_cancel to conclude

Tags: pthreads

I'm using pthreads that don't allocate any local variables. For reasons I won't go into here, I need a `pthread_cancel()` option, and the threads I'm writing should be able to support it (no resources to clean up, OK to stop execution at any point). At the moment, I have a problem because `pthread_cancel` returns before the pthread is actually finished running, causing problems for shared resources I want to touch only after thread cancellation.

Is there any way I can know when my pthread has well and truly concluded? Is there perhaps a function for this I haven't found, or a parameter I'm not familiar with?

Would

```
pthread_cancel(thread_handle);
pthread_join(thread_handle, NULL);
```

do the trick, or is that not guaranteed (since `thread_handle` may already be invalid)?

I'm pretty new to pthreads, so best practices welcome (beyond "don't use `pthread_cancel()`," which I've already learned :P ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html) manual page is actually doing it. It's safe.

```
s = pthread_cancel(thr);
if (s != 0)
    handle_error_en(s, "pthread_cancel");

/* Join with thread to see what its exit status was */

s = pthread_join(thr, &res);
if (s != 0)
    handle_error_en(s, "pthread_join");
```

Answer (score 1):

Until you call `pthread_join` on a joinable thread, its tid remains valid. If the thread is joinable (which it must be for `pthread_cancel` to be safe), then the thread_handle must still be valid.

If the thread was detached, it wouldn't even be safe to call `pthread_cancel`. What if the thread terminated just as you called it?